# Unable to save data using Horizon on private testnet

Tags: stellar-core, operations, private-network

I have a Horizon server `0.12.3` and Stellar-Core `9.2.0rc6` running locally. When I send a create account operation using the root account as the source, the new account creates properly.

However, when I try to send a manage data operation, trying to save the data name "test" with value "hi", I get a `tx_failed` message, with a blank operations string:

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed",
  "title": "Transaction Failed",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html",
  "extras": {
    "envelope_xdr": "AAAAAN5DEJn9DwVZhhctyWBlUcyVHQ7AXerKrur0kNQCKhM7AAAAZAAAAGcAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAoAAAAEdGVzdAAAAAEAAAACaGkAAAAAAAAAAAABAioTOwAAAEDBWxUL8cBuFoTRz7rYqoFxfGU4f6klq0Targt78zyvIq9j4uPHykfWnUwUjCZUHXTCIwT5dUkfMrHuHavsuj0I",
    "result_codes": {
      "transaction": "tx_failed",
      "operations": [
        ""
      ]
    },
    "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAK/////wAAAAA="
  }
}
```

Error code is

```
QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ProtocolInvalidOperationError)
```

Now, when I connect to `horizon-testnet.stellar.org` instead of my local instance (`localhost:8000`) the same code I'm using works just fine. I'm using the C++ SDK.

Can someone shed some light on why the operations array returns a blank string? I don't see any logs in stellar-core itself about this transaction; if it was throwing an exception, it would be helpful.

I'm trying to save data using the new account, not the root account. The next sequence number I'm getting from the new account is 442381631488. Here's the dump of the account:

*Query* :

```
QUrl("http://localhost:8000/accounts/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P")
```

*Response*:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/accounts/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P"
    },
    "transactions": {
      "href": "/accounts/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P/transactions{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "operations": {
      "href": "/accounts/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P/operations{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "payments": {
      "href": "/accounts/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P/payments{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "effects": {
      "href": "/accounts/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P/effects{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "offers": {
      "href": "/accounts/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P/offers{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "trades": {
      "href": "/accounts/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P/trades{?cursor,limit,order}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "data": {
      "href": "/GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P/data/{key}",
      "templated": true
    }
  },
  "id": "GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P",
  "paging_token": "",
  "account_id": "GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P",
  "sequence": "442381631488",
  "subentry_count": 0,
  "thresholds": {
    "low_threshold": 0,
    "med_threshold": 0,
    "high_threshold": 0
  },
  "flags": {
    "auth_required": false,
    "auth_revocable": false
  },
  "balances": [
    {
      "balance": "50.9909000",
      "asset_type": "native"
    }
  ],
  "signers": [
    {
      "public_key": "GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P",
      "weight": 1,
      "key": "GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P",
      "type": "ed25519_public_key"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "test123": "asdf"
  }
}
```

Account address is `GDPEGEEZ7UHQKWMGC4W4SYDFKHGJKHIOYBO6VSVO5L2JBVACFIJTWZ5P`
sequence number is `442381631488` The data you see associated with the account wasn't a successful transaction, I manually injected it into the SQL database to see if it showed up in the account dump. I have tried sending a `manage data operation` both before the manual injection, and after it; it yields a blank `operations` string either way.

Comment: Please upgrade to latest stellar-core and horizon and it will work.

Comment: I've upgraded to Stellar-core 9.2.0 with Horizon 0.12.3 and still no luck. Also tried compiling Stellar-core from the master branch which should be the latest and greatest code--still, no luck. Can you tell me which versions should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the Core using an outdated version of the protocol. I had to upgrade the protocol to version 9 by using:
`stellar-core -c 'upgrades?mode=set&upgradetime=yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss&protocolversion=9`

So, just because you're running Core version 9 doesn't mean you're actually using version 9 protocol. The command above upgrades the network.